# Error: Instance : Num (a -> b) when I try to get the sign of the elements of a list

Tags: list, haskell

This is what I want to do:

```
INPUT: [1,2,3,-1,-2,-3]
OUTPUT:[1,1,1,-1,-1,-1]
```

I tried this:

```
signNum (x:n) = map(if x>0 
            then 1 
            else -1)n
```

Can anyone tell me where I've made a mistake in the logic?

Comment: Note that there already is a `signum` function you can use.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that `map` expects a function. So you have to wrap your `if` statement in a lambda. However, this will still not do exactly what you want. Instead of breaking the list into its head and tail, your really want to map your function over the whole list.

Remember that `map` just takes a function and applies it to each element. Since you want to turn each element into either `1` or `-1`, you just need to map the appropriate function over your list.

So in the end, you get:

```
sigNum ls = map (\ x -> if x > 0 then 1 else - 1) ls
```

Comment: Thnx Jelvis.I know I am bothering you by givng such a simple task for you. Would u pls tell me exatly where do I use lamda function style rather than [x|x<xs,condition] style?

Comment: I have also tries this: **bold**signNum xs= x1
where
x1= map checkSign xs
checkSign x  =if x>0 but it shoes the error. Why?
   then 1
   else -1

Comment: `[x|x<-xs, ...]` can only represent a sublist of the original list `xs` - it can't transform the elements of `xs`. You want to change `2` into `1` and `-3` into `-1` so a simple list comprehension isn't going to get you there.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is probably easier to break the function down into smaller parts.

At the very lowest level, one can compute the `signum` of a single number, i.e.:

```
signum :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
signum x = if x > 0 then 1 else -1
```

Once you have this, you can then use it on a list of numbers, like you would for any function:

```
signNum ls = map signum ls
```

(p.s. what is `signum 0` meant to be? Your current definition has `signum 0 = -1`.

If you need to expand the function to include this case, it might be better to use guards:

```
signum x | x < 0 = -1
         | x == 0 = 0
         | otherwise = 1
```

or a case statement:

```
signum x = case compare x 0 of 
             LT -> -1
             EQ -> 0
             GT -> 1
```

)

Comment: thanx. thanx a lot to take me deep down in it,.I am thnkful to u both. U see maybe , I asked jelvis a question:Would u pls tell me exatly where do I use lamda function style rather than [x|x<xs,condition] style? can u pls explain it to me?

Comment: @SaugataBose, [have a look at this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#lambdas). (It would probably be helpful and interesting to read the [whole book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) too :) )

Answer (score 1):

Your comments suggest you'd like to be able to do this with a comprehension.

### How to use a comprehension

If you do want to do this with a comprehension, you can do

```
signNum ls = [ if x>0 then 1 else -1| x <- ls ]
```

### How not to use a comprehension

...but you can't put the condition on the right hand side

```
brokenSignNum ls = [ 1| x <- ls, x > 0 ]
```

Because putting a condition on the right hand side removes anything that
doesn't satisfy the condition - all your negatives get ignored! This would 
shorten your list rather than replace the elements. Let's try

```
brokenSignNum2 ls = [ 1| x <- ls, x > 0 ] ++ [ -1| x <- ls, x <= 0 ]
```

This has the same length as your original list but all the positives are at the front.

> Summary: you have to put this conditional expression on the left hand side 
>   becuase that's the only place substitution can happen - on the right hand side it does deletion.

### Is zero negative?

Note that your if statement counts 0 as negative. Are you sure you want that? Perhaps you'd be better with defining the sign of a number seperately:

```
sign x | x == 0 = 0   -- if x is zero, use zero
       | x > 0 =  1   -- use 1 for positives
       | x < 0 = -1   -- use -1 for negatives

workingSignNum1 ls = [sign x | x <- ls]
```

But `sign` is (almost) the same as the function `signum`, so we may as well use that

```
workingSignNum2 ls = [signum x | x <- ls]
```

### Making it tidier

Now that's a lot of syntax for what basically means "replace `x` with `sign x` all along the list `ls`". We do that kind of thing a lot, so we could write a function to do it:

```
replaceUsing :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
replaceUsing f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
```

but there's already a function that does that! It's called `map`. So we can use map on our list:

```
quiteSlickSignNum :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
quiteSlickSignNum ls = map signum ls
```

or even slicker:

```
slickSignNum :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
slickSignNum = map signum
```

which is how I would have defined it.

### Why did you say `sign` was *almost* the same as `signum`?

`sign` takes a number and returns a number, `1`, `0`, or `-1`, but what's the type of `1`?
Well, `1` has the type `Num a => a` so you can use it with any numeric type. This means
`sign` takes any type of number and returns any type of number, so its type is

```
sign :: (Num a,Num b) => a -> b
```

so my version of `sign` can give you a different type. If you try it out, you'll find that `3 * sign 4.5` gives you `3`, not `3.0`, so you can get an Integer out of it, but also if you do `3.14 * sign 7.4`, you get `3.14`, so you can get a decimal type too. By contrast,

```
signum :: Num a => a -> a
```

so it can only give you back the type you gave it - `3 * signum 4.5` gives you `3.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "no instance for `Num`" is one of the trickiest for new Haskellers to decipher. First, here's the fully polymorphic type signature for the function you are trying to write (I added this to the source file in order to get the same error as you):

```
signNum :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]
```

**Finding the error**

Now, the compile error message says:

> Could not deduce (Num (a -> a)) from the context (Ord a, Num a)
>         arising from the literal `1' at prog.hs:3:17

Notice that the error message gives us the location of the problem. It says that "the literal 1" at `file_name.hs:line_number:column_number` is the problem.

```
signNum (x:n) = map(if x>0 
            then 1 -- <-- here's the problem! (according to that message)
            else -1)n
```

**Understanding the error**

Now, the error message also suggests some possible fixes, but whenever you run into "no instance for `Num`", the suggested "possible fixes" are almost always wrong, so ignore them. (I wish GHC would provide better error messages for `Num`-related stuff like this).

Recall what the error message said:

> Could not deduce (Num (a -> a)) ... arising from the literal `1' ...

What this means is that you put a literal `1` somewhere where the context expected something of type
`a -> a`. `1` is obviously not a function, so either the context is wrong, or the number 1 is wrong.

So what *is* the context of the literal 1?

**Finding the error (precisely)**

```
(if x > 0
  then <<hole>>
  else -1)
```

If statements in Haskell produce a value. The branches of an if statement must have the same type, and the type of the if statement is determined by the type of the branches.

Here, the other branch has the value `-1`, which is a number. So we therefore expect the `<<hole>>` to have the same type: a number. Well, this obviously isn't the problem (since 1 *is* a number), so let's look at the context of *that* expression.

```
map <<hole>> n
```

The `map` function expects a function as its first argument. However, we know the `<<hole>>` will produce a number. Eureka! Here's the discrepancy: we're giving `map` a number where it expects a function.

**Correcting the error**

The obvious solution -- now that we know precisely what and where the problem is -- is to give `map` a function, rather than a number. See the various other answers for details.